# Ionic simple components not including

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'll keep this really simple in the hope that someone knows what I'm doing wrong. I'm fairly new to Ionic and Angular. I'm trying to include a simple reusable component in my `home.page.ts`.

**home.page.ts**

```
<ion-content>
  testing
  <app-speakers></app-speakers>
</ion-content>
```

I've imported it in the `app.module.ts` and declared it

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SpeakersComponent } from './components/speakers/speakers.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SpeakersComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'agenda',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/agenda/agenda.module').then( m => m.AgendaPageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

The speaker component is generated so it's all standard at the moment

**speakers.componennt.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-speakers',
  templateUrl: './speakers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./speakers.component.scss'],
})
export class SpeakersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**speakers.component.html**

```
<p>
  speakers works!
</p>
```

But all that's displayed is the 'testing' text. The console says that `'app-speakers' is not a known element`. Am I missing a library or something, or is it something plainly obvious?

Comment: Where you are loading `HomePageModule`? still, some information required. Try to declare speakers component `HomePageModule`

Comment: Ah sorry, I've now added my code for app-routing.module.ts above now. That imports HomePageModule

Comment: Ok, I've worked it out I think. Because of the way the homepage is getting imported, I need to declare the SpeakerComponent in the home.module.ts declarations, not in the app.module.ts. Hmm, how annoying!